# Update table with complex WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: **WebPages**(including parent site ID) and **Results**(including parent webpage ID).

I'm want to write a stored procedure that updates the column "**FirstSeen**" *for all records with a specific site ID*.

For example (this code is not working):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP]
    @SiteId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[Results]
        SET [dbo].[Results].[FirstSeen] = GetDate()
        WHERE [dbo].[WebPages].[Id] = [dbo].[Results].[WebPages_Id] AND [dbo].[WebPages].[WebSites_Id]=@SiteId

END
GO
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MarkAllResultsAsReaded, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "dbo.WebPages.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MarkAllResultsAsReaded, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "dbo.WebPages.WebSites_Id" could not be bound.
```

Do you know how to solve this?

I'm using SQL-Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use tables other than the current one in an update without explicitly in a join, like this:

```
UPDATE r
    SET r.[FirstSeen] = GetDate()
FROM [dbo].[Results] r
INNER JOIN [dbo].[WebPages] p ON p.[Id] = r.[WebPages_Id]
WHERE p.[WebSites_Id]=@SiteId
```

The reason why you need a join is that your `UPDATE` references two tables - `Results` and `WebPages`.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to join both the tables and do UPDATE like below, cause you are actually trying to update all the rows in `Results` table where there is a matching record present in `webpages` table.

```
UPDATE r
    SET [FirstSeen] = GetDate()

    FROM [dbo].[Results] r
    JOIN [dbo].[WebPages] w
    ON w.[Id] = r.[WebPages_Id] 
    AND w.[WebSites_Id]=@SiteId
```

Answer (score 0):

You do a subquery:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Results]
SET [dbo].[Results].[FirstSeen] = GetDate()
WHERE [Results].[WebPages_Id] IN (Select [WebPages].[Id] From [dbo].[WebPages]Where [WebPages].[WebSites_Id]=@SiteId)
```

The `JOIN` will give you better performance as shown in other answers.